# How can i enable/disable kernel kaslr, smep and smap

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86

I am wondering how i can enable or disable this 3 features from linux kernel:

- kaslr
- smep
- smap

I have read i have to add something in kernel's command line to enable this features.
I have looked into /proc/cmdline. I do not see anything about smep.

But, when i ask /proc/cpuinfo, i can see smep is enabled.

So my question is: What is the correct way to enable or disable this 3 features.
And what is the correct way to check if they are enabled at runtime

Thanks

Comment: **Single problem** per question, please. For disabling kaslr, see that question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397939/turning-off-kaslr-to-debug-linux-kernel-using-qemu-and-gdb.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that i am not really sure the kaslr is really enabled or disable. I can put whatever i want in command line. I want to see if the kernel is really protected or not...

Comment: "i am not really sure the kaslr is really enabled or disable.", "I want to see if the kernel is really protected or not" - So, these should be actual questions, shouldn't they? Otherwise, how could we answer your original questions, if you simple don't want such answers? And again, please separate question post for separated questions. As you can see, disabling **different options** and checking them can be **performed differently**.

Comment: There is no way to check a flag (somewhere in /proc ?) in order to see if the kernel takes care of the arguments

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following kernel boot parameter to disable these features:

- `nosmap`: Disables SMAP. It's supported starting with 3.7, which is also the first version that supports SMAP.
- `nosmep`: Disables SMEP. It's supported starting with 3.0, which is also the first version that supports SMEP.
- `nokaslr`: Disables KASLR.  It's supported starting with 3.14, which is also the first version that supports KASLR.

The kernel also enables these features by default at boot-time (if supported by the underlying CPU and the kernel version). They are never enabled or disabled after booting.

You can programmatically disable/enable SMAP and SMEP by simply changing the corresponding flags in the `CR4` register on all logical cores using a kernel module.

Comment: I have wrote a kernel module which displays CR4 register value in dmesg with printk. I have 4.19 kernel. You are true about smep: It is enabled by default. nosmep can disable it. But smap is not enabled and i do not know what to do for enabling it

Comment: @Bob5421 What is your processor? It may not support SMAP.

Comment: It is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570S CPU @ 3.10GHz

Comment: Your CPU (Ivy Bridge) does not support SMAP. It's supported starting with [Broadwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadwell_(microarchitecture)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if there is a control bit (like CR4 ones) to check if kaslr is enabled ?

Comment: @Bob5421 No, KASLR is completely implemented in the kernel, it's not an ISA feature.

Comment: what does ISA stands for ?

Comment: @Bob5421 Instruction Set Architecture, which is x86 in this case. SMAP is a feature offered to the OS from the ISA and the OS can enable it or disable it by setting a flag in some register. But KASLR is an OS feature, not an ISA one, so it's impossible to control it by setting some flag in some register because the ISA is not aware of it.