# Get x86 SMEP CPU flag from user mode

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, intel

I am writing a usermode tool that watches for changes to CPU flags such as WP from CR0, and SMEP from CR4. I can read the WP bit using `smsw %rax` but there is no similar opcode for reading CR4 (or its SMEP bit).

Is there a way to get the state of SMEP from usermode ?

Comment: Unlikely. The only reason why SMSW isn't a privileged instruction is for compatibility with the 80286.

Answer (score 6):

The Linux kernel never changes the SMEP bit after booting. See [How can i enable/disable kernel kaslr, smep and smap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615925/how-can-i-enable-disable-kernel-kaslr-smep-and-smap). By default, it's enabled if it's supported on the processor starting with kernel 3.0. So if you want to check whether SMEP is enabled, do the following:

- Check whether SMEP is supported by executing `cpuid` with leaf 0x7. The processor supports SMEP if EBX[0x7] is 1.
- If SMEP is supported, check whether `nosmep` is specified in the kernel command line argument list. This can be done using either the `sysctl` system call or something like `cat /proc/cmdline | grep nosmep`.

If it's supported on the processor and `nosmep` is not specified, then it's enabled. Otherwise, it's disabled or not supported.